# Jquery dynamically load div issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hey guys i am new to HTML and Jquery. Now i am able to replace a container div from my navigation menu using load function but the script does not work if it is called from the container i want to change itself. For example i am running this script

```
     $("#pagehome").click(function(){
     $("#container").load("home.html #wraper", function ()
```

when i call this from another div section(navigation menu) it works just fine and the div
section of container gets replaced with #wraper div of another page

```
 <div id=navigationmenu>
 <a id="pagehome"  href="#"><;img src"..."/></a>  
 </div>
 </pre>
```

but when i try to call the script from container div it does not get executed

```
 <div id=container>
 <a id="pagehome"  href="#"><img src"..."/>
 </div>
```

Comment: whether both these elements are present in the page at the same time?

Comment: I'm seeing 2 possible problems here. 1) duplication ID's 2) The `#container` is dynamically loaded

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes there are present in the page,changed the id still does not executed.Yes the container is dynamically changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#pagehome', function(){
    ...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: No this does not work. I am starting to think that is not possible to call a div to change from inside that div

Comment: @JimBoyHac If you want to share some functionality among different elements then try to use classes instead of ids. As stated above in the comments you might have an ID conflict, ID must be unique on a page.